# HA - Limit approaching positive infinity 1/-1

Tags: calculus, limits

I was working out a HA for graphing as follows:

$$
\lim _{x \rightarrow -\infty} \frac{3-x}{x-1}=-1
$$

Which was ok. But lost a point for the below:

$$
\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{3-x}{x-1}=-1
$$

That I should have shown it as $1/-1 = -1^{-1}$.

What's the difference?

Comment: Honestly, hell if I know. The answer is correct, and $-1^{-1} = -1$ anyways.

Comment: what does HA mean?  Houston Astros? Hallelujah Amen? Heloise and Abelard?

Comment: @WillJagy horizontal asymptote I think

Comment: yes. horizontal asymptote.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer. Ok. Thanks.